# How to get total number of views from ViewFlipper?

Tags: android, viewflipper

How can I get the number of views of `ViewFlipper` ? I need to refresh `ViewFlipper` after all views have been seen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `getChildCount()`, since `ViewFlipper` is a `ViewGroup`.